Error: Cannot find -lgridstore when I try to install Python Client on GridDB
I'm encountering an issue while trying to install the Python Client. Every time I attempt to make the Python Client, I get the following error: "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgridstore".
I downloaded the Python Client from GitHub using the following command:
$ wget https://github.com/griddb/python_client/archive/0.8.1.tar.gz

Then, I unzipped the file using:
$ tar xvzf 0.8.1.tar.gz

Next, I installed the necessary prerequisites by downloading SWIG:
$ wget https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/swig/swig-3.0.12.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz swig-3.0.12.tar.gz
$ cd swig-3.0.12
$ ./configure
$ make 
$ sudo make install

After that, I installed PCRE using the command:
$ sudo yum install pcre2-devel.x86_64

Finally, I attempted to create the Python Client using this command:
$ cd ../python_client
$ make

However, I keep encountering the error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgridstore" during the make process.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue, as it's currently impeding my progress. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
